# Unable to retrieve User Profile in designer workflow

Tags: designer-workflow, user-profile-service

I am using SharePoint 2010. My scenario is I was trying to use the Data source “User Profiles” in a workflow and I’m getting the following error. Kindly help if anyone faced similar issue and succeeded in resolving it.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

People who are facing this issue..I have tried different ways and finally fixed this

- Change SQL database permissions on the search database.
- It was erroring for me at first, then once we granted the exec_ permissions it was able to see the User Profiles dropdown items.

Thanks.